# CiviCRM Database Upgrade from 4.7.16 to 4.7.28 is hanging

Tags: joomla, upgrade, database

I am trying to upgrade my Joomla civiCRM database from 4.7.16 to 4.7.28. The component upgraded fine but when I try to upgrade the database after following all of the preparation steps, it hangs and makes not progress. I've looked at all of the similar problems, but nothing helps me with my error. I have two questions, how do I know what's going on? And my second question is what is going on and how to I get it to complete the upgrade?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you check apache error and CiviCRM log? If you have database access can you paste the result of below query

```
SELECT id, version FROM civicrm_domain;
```

Comment: Here's the result of the query: 4.7.17.upgrade

Comment: I also added a picture of the error message I received after running the upgrade script overnight.

Comment: Anything in CiviCRM logs?

Comment: Does civicrm_financial_trxn table have millions of records?

Comment: I'm godaddy, where do I find the logs?  The databases are small.

Comment: Should be under media/civicrm/ConfigLogs/ with CiviCRM.xxxxxxxx.log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70935/discussion-between-tee-strong-and-pradeep-nayak).

Comment: Its seems like there is problem while trying to upgrade from 4.7.16 to 4.7.28, when localization is turned on. Since the new code base i.e 4.7.28 on upgrade screen tries to load profile links through JS call which causes DB: Error with no field found for 'cancel_button_text' which is added in 4.7.25. I would recommend to do incremental upgrade from 4.7.16 to 4.7.24 and then from 4.7.24 to 4.7.28. Let me know how it goes?